# Pandas remove group if difference between first and last row in group exceeds value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtering

I have a dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
df['X'] = [3,8,11,6,7,8]
df['name'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]

    X  name
0   3     1
1   8     1
2  11     1
3   6     2
4   7     2
5   8     2
```

For each group within 'name' and want to remove that group if the difference between the first and last row of that group is smaller than a specified value d_dif in absolute way:

For example, when d_dif= 5, I want to get:

```
    X  name
0   3     1
1   8     1
2  11     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is increasingly in `X`, you can use `groupby().transform()` and `np.ptp`

```
threshold = 5
ranges = df.groupby('name')['X'].transform(np.ptp)

df[ranges > threshold]
```

If you only care about `first` and `last`, then `transform` just `first` and `last`:

```
threshold = 5
groups = df.groupby('name')['X']

ranges = groups.transform('last') - groups.transform('first')

df[ranges.abs() > threshold]
```

Comment: thanks. what does the ['X'] do after groupby('name) ? And then how is ranges defined?

Comment: `groupby()['X']` only select column `X` to perform later operations, similar to how you do `df['X'].mean()` for example. You can use the second approach and print `group.transform('last')` to see how ranges is defined.